# Show tags for each entry

Tags: tags

I have one tag for each entry.

```
 - Entry1
     Tag1
 - Entry2
     Tag2
```

Now I want to show them in the title of each entry. But it doesn't work.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mainEntry').limit(4) %}
{% set tag = entry.mainEntryTag.first() %}
  <h2>{{ tag }} {{ entry.title }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

This results in displaying only the globally first tag:

```
- Entry1
     Tag1
- Entry2
     Tag1
```

If I just write: `{% set tag = entry.projektart %}` I get the error: `Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string`

How can I get to current entry tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close. Change "set tag" to "set tags" so you have:

```
{% set tags = entry.projektart %}
```

And then loop through the tags:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    {{ tag }}
{% else %}
    No tags found
{% endfor %}
```

You could also simplify this and instead of setting the "tags" variable you could write the following:

```
{% for tag in entry.projektart %}
```